# Finding partial derivatives of a given function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I must calculate $\displaystyle \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$ from $f(x,y)=\displaystyle\frac{4 \cdot \pi^2 \cdot x}{y^2}$. $$\displaystyle \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{4 \cdot \pi^2}{y^2}$$ $$\displaystyle \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=\frac{-8 \cdot \pi^2 \cdot x}{y^3}$$  Is it correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, is correct.

Comment: @rlartiga, thanks soo much! :)

Comment: Very well for a homework post. You write the question and your solution (and/or the attempts to get it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a homework, let us use the definitions of partial derivatives to check results, which are normally quickly obtained by following the  rule "keep all fixed except for the variable w.r.t. you compute the partial derivative and use results from Analysis I/Calculus".

Then

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y):=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}=
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{4\pi^2}{y^2h}(x+h-x)= \frac{4\pi^2}{y^2}.$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y):=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}=
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{4\pi^2x}{h}\left(\frac{1}{(y+h)^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}\right)= 
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{4\pi^2x}{h}\left(\frac{h(-2y-h)}{y^2(y+h)^2}\right)=
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{4\pi^2x(-2y-h)}{y^2(y+h)^2}=\frac{-8\pi^2x}{y^3}.$$

The computations in the OP are correct.